# How to store lists of data in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, expo

I'm a beginner React Native user and I was wondering how I can go about storing lists of data in a file that can be displayed as text on screen? For example, I want to store different work schedules depending on the day. So what is one way I can store a bunch of different fixed schedules and be able to display the data according to what kind of day it is? I am using React Native with Expo. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you reading the docs? this is the page for lists https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-listview and here's a page for storage https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FlatList component is most likely what you're looking for. It can render data flexibly with a pile of configurations.

Here's a simple example with a set of data, a render item method, and the list itself

```
renderItem(item) {
return (
  <View>
   <Text> {item.key} + {item.employee1}</Text>
  </View>
);
}

const scheduleData = [
 {key: 'Monday', employee1: "john"},
 {key: 'Tuesday', employee1: "jep"},
 {key: 'Wednesday' , employee1: "jabouris"},
 {key: 'Thursday', employee1: "jennifer"},
 {key: 'Friday', employee1: "jenalyn"},
 {key: 'Saturday', employee1: "josh"},
 {key: 'Sunday', employee1: "jenna"}
 ];

 <FlatList
    data={scheduleData}
    renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
  />
```

Where the renderItem would be placed by the other methods in the class(outside the render method), and the data set was placed outside of the return, and the flatlist would be placed in the return.

More examples and information on lists can be found here: [React Native List Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-listview)

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed!